# How to use Traefik as autorotating forward proxy

Tags: proxy, backend, tor, traefik

I know that Traefik is manly used as a reverse proxy, but I would like to use Traefik as a autorotating forward proxy similar to the following projects:

[free-proxy-rotator](https://github.com/jaxgeller/free-proxy-rotator)

[rotating-proxy](https://github.com/mattes/rotating-proxy)

The basic idea is that I have a list of proxy IPs and would like to configure Traefik to autorotate all incoming requests between those proxies.

I've started with a very simple config that should return my public IP if I `curl ip.localhost` but I don't seem to be on the right track.

```
################################################################
# Global configuration
################################################################

defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

################################################################
# File configuration backend
################################################################
[file]

################################################################
# rules
################################################################
  [backends]
    [backends.backend2]
      [backends.backend2.servers.server1]
      url = "http://api.ipify.org:80"
      weight = 1

  [frontends]
    [frontends.frontend2]
    backend = "backend2"
      [frontends.frontend2.routes.test_1]
      rule = "Host:ip.localhost"
```

Comment: Did you get it running? Does traefik actually support an ip address as a backend?